# Text disappears when I add the tooltip class

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to create a tooltip using CSS and HTML, which should be pretty straightforward. But, for some weird reason when I add the "tooltip" class to my element, the text the I want to hover over disappears. This only happens when I add the tooltip class, I can give the text other class names and it works just fine.

Here is my code.

```css
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
 width: 120px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
 border-radius: 6px;

 /* Position the tooltip text */
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 125%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -60px;

 /* Fade in tooltip */
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover > .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p> This is a paragraph that includes a <span class="tooltip">tooltip<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></span> . </p>
```

This is what it looks like when I run the code:

[image]

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` is setted to elements with class `.tooltiptext` that are inside elements with class `.tooltip`, so it is expected to "disappear"

Comment: I was thinking that might be the problem, but changing the visibility to "visible" does not make a difference.

Comment: Also `opacity: 0` will make it invisible. `z-index: 1` can also cause it to be behind some other elements.  You'll need a `.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext{...}` to adjust it to appear when hovered

Comment: @RNY, all you need to do set `visibility: visible` and `opacity: 1` to the `.tooltiptext` when you hover.   I posted this as an answer with a fully working example.  Please accept as the answer if this works for you. :)

Comment: with your last edit, your presented code works as expected without any issue. So this question is now available to be closed as "*a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*" Please, add your current code in a way that we can really reproduce the problem, **[mcve]**

Comment: @Calvin, I don't understand? His tooltip was not showing because he didn't have a :hover definition, So I recreated his problem, and provided a a working answer and solution.  I don't understand, `can no longer be reproduced`?

Comment: @BryanElliott run the snippet above, are you able to reproduce the problem that OP is saying it has? I can't, for me it is working in his own snippet, tooltip is showing for me. He must provide a code that reproduce the problem. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm saying that OP's code is also working here, so the question is not reproducible

Comment: @Calvin You're correct, the provided code works just fine now. The text disappears when I load Bootstrap 4 onto my HTML file.

Comment: bootstrap have its own definition of `.tooltip` class, so it is probably overriding the one you are styling

Comment: @Calvin, Ohh.. Ok.. I see.. It was  a different issue, related to bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the tooltip on hover, like this:

Add this:

```
.tooltip:hover > .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

here's the entire working code:

```css
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
 width: 120px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
 border-radius: 6px;

 /* Position the tooltip text */
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 125%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -60px;

 /* Fade in tooltip */
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover > .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<p> This is a paragraph that includes a <span class="tooltip">tooltip<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></span> . </p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code! However, the text is still not visible. I added a picture to illustrate what happens when I run the code.

Comment: Press the `Run code snippet` in the answer.  This is working.  If you're not seeing the tooltip, it must be something else in your code that is causing it.  Try setting the `z-index: 100` in the :hover definition.. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @RNY, it must be coming from something else that you did not include in your code snippet.  Because the code snippet example is working.  Maybe you have another definition also setting `.tooltip`, maybe making it color: white, or visibility hidden or something like that?  Do you have a link where I could view it?

Comment: You're correct, the code that I gave you is working. Apparently, when I load Bootstrap 4 onto my HTML file, this causes the tooltip to stop working.

Comment: @RNY, Ohh, ok then, glad you figured it out. :)